# nested if in haskell

Tags: haskell, nested-if

//edit 5
when the i use only these 2 lines

```
  index :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
  index a b = and [x `elem` a |x <- b]
```

it works fine!!!!

eg:

index ["asd","asdd","dew"] ["asdd","asdad"]

False

But when i use the entire code mentioned below

```
empty [] = True
empty _ = False

    index a b = do
             if empty a
              then do putStrLn "a is empty"
                      else return ()
             if empty b
              then do putStrLn "b is empty"
                      else return ()
        where
          index :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
          index a b = and [x `elem` a |x <- b]
```

theres no output!! and thats the issue i got!!

//edit 6

```
index a b = do index'
         if empty a
          then do putStrLn "a is empty"
                  else return ()
         if empty b
          then do putStrLn "b is empty"
                  else return ()
    where
      index' :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
      index' a b = and [x `elem` a |x <- b]
```

thanks

Comment: "the last line which is the main function of the program works fine without the nested if above": It won't, `index'` won't even type check...

Comment: Regarding your edit: both snippets work fine, I don't get an 'unexpected symbol' error. However, you have given two functions the same name, this way you can't call the second `index` from the first.

Comment: Which of your question have already been answered now?

Comment: please refer edit 4. thats the question i need to ask.

Comment: What should index do now? Should it check whether who lists are empty and make some output or should it check wheter b is a subset of a?

Comment: first i need to check whether they are empty.
second i need to check whether elements in b are present in a.

Comment: Check for emptiness with `empty` or `null` (which is a builtin function). Use `and [x `elem` a |x <- b]` to check wheter b is a subset of a (call your function subset instead of index please)

What's your problem? What output should your function produce for two given lists? Please give some more information or maybe pseudocode in your question.

Comment: as i have mentioned in the question if the user enters 
index ["asd","asdd","dew"] ["asdd","asdad"]
the output must be -> False

Comment: That's nothing but `index a b = and [x `elem` a |x <- b]`. What's the problem? What do you `putStrLn` etc. need for? The code above just prints whether the lists are empty.

Comment: if i say index [] []

the output would be True

Comment: Regarding edit 4: You still have two functions with the same name `index`. The function at top level is the one that is called, the function in the `where` clause is never called.

Comment: oh! how im i supposed to call it? that was the inital problem! refer edit 6, but this appraoch doesnt work.

Comment: @Tom, Nathan was able to help me out using pattern-matching and it worked fine.

how can do the same using this, indentation approach. I would like to know to solve this issue in this way.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is a little off-topic since maybe you are trying to learn the layout rule and how to nest ifs, but the code you show in revision 6 is just using `if` to do error checking. I would just do the error checking via pattern matching instead of `if`.

```
index [] _ = putStrLn "a is empty"
index _ [] = putStrLn "b is empty"
index a b = putStrLn (show index')
    where index' = and [x `elem` a | x <- b]
```

(You don't need the `return ()` after `putStrLn` because it already returns `()` for you.)

Pattern matching is a lot easier to get right because it doesn't require a lot of indentation, etc.

---

Edit:

I changed the definition of `index'` a little from yours. In my version it's a local variable instead of a local function. In Haskell, there's not much difference, it's just that `index'` uses `a` and `b` from the surrounding `index` function, so it doesn't need to take parameters. (Admittedly, `index'` is not such a good name for a variable.)

Also I left off the type annotation because I don't usually write them. But they are helpful when something isn't working. Here is what it would look like:

```
    where index' :: Bool
          index' = and [x `elem` a | x <- b]
```

Comment: why dont i need to define the type like

index' :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool

Comment: The compiler generally can deduce the types automatically, so you don't need to declare them manually if you don't want to. But it's usually better to declare them because it helps to find the problematic code in case of type errors. In this case you could declare the type of index as "[String] -> [String] -> IO ()" or more generally as "(Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> IO ()".

Answer (score 2):

An `if` construct in Haskell is a expression.
That means it must always evaluate to a value, so the `else` part is mandatory.

Also, the first part of `if` must be a boolean, so you can't call `index'` there, since that returns a `[Int]`, not a `Bool`.

I would say, start with something like this:

```
if isEmpty a
then putStrLn "a is empty"
else if isEmpty b
     then putStrLn "b is empty"
     else putStrLn "neither are empty"
```

Comment: ok, well i tried it this way and i still get an error as "Syntax error in expression (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad layout)
"

index as bs = if isEmpty as
     then putStrLn "a is empty"
     else if isEmpty bs
    then putStrLn "b is empty"
    else putStrLn "neither are empty"
 where 
  index' :: [String] -> [String] -> [Int]
  index' as bs = index' True [(elem a bs) | a <- as]

Comment: You'll need `do` to sequence the outputs.

Comment: Than you probably do have a problem with your layout. Make sure the `then` and `else` keywords are indented to at least the level of the `if` keyword. In your current question, the `else` is indented wrong. Also, make sure you only use spaces for layout, tabs will mess thing up.

Comment: @Dario, the you don't really need `do` syntax in this example. In this case, the expression will be of type `IO ()`, because `putStrLn` is of that type. `do` syntax is just syntax sugar if you want to bind multiple expressions, but that's not necessary here.

Comment: I'll have to bind multiple expressions - The programm may output

a is empty
b is empty

Comment: Right, my example will only output one string, because it is a nested `if`. Should you want to print out multiple strings, you would have to bind two expressions, then you could use the `do` notation.

Answer (score 0):

IO operations in Haskell are a bit difficult because they need so called [monads](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads)
You would need a special `do`-notion here to sequence the outputs.

Write it like this:

```
empty [] = True
empty _ = False

index a b = do
         if empty a
          then do putStrLn "a is empty"
          else return ()
         if empty b
          then do putStrLn "b is empty"
          else return ()
```

Or Maybe you could just return the strings and use `putStrLn` separately.
You `index'` must return a boolean value when it should be used as an if condition!

Comment: You won't need the `do` syntax here, if you remove all the `do`s, your code will still work.

Comment: The `empty` function here already exists in the Prelude, it's called `null` and it's defined in exactly the same way.

Comment: How would the code look without do? It makes two separate outputs so both conditions and `putStrLn`s must be sequenced monadically = do.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't read your code properly. You are right, you need the outer `do`. Btw, there is also a function for `if b then something else return ()` called `when`. You can use it like so: `when (empty a) (putStrLn "a is empty")`. It is in the `Control.Monad` module.

Comment: index a b = when (empty a) (putStrLn "a is empty")
            when (empty b) (putStrLn "b is empty")

why isn't this possible? 
index a b = when (empty a) (putStrLn "a is empty") worked fine!

thanks

Comment: You will need `do` notation to sequence the two calls to `when`.

Comment: hmm 1 more thing

after 'do' why isnt it possible to define the index type like
empty [] = True
empty _ = False

index a b = do
         if empty a
          then do putStrLn "a is empty"
                  else return ()
         if empty b
          then do putStrLn "b is empty"
                  else return ()
 where
   index :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
          index a b = and [x `elem` a |x <- b]

Comment: or like this

or

import Control.Monad
empty [] = True
empty _ = False

index a b = do  when (empty a) (putStrLn "a is empty")
                when (empty b) (putStrLn "b is empty")
 where
   index :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
          index a b = and [x `elem` a |x <- b]

Comment: @dlna, could you update your question instead of posting comments? The comments are hard to read without indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
index a b = if index' [] bs
                       then putStrLn "a is empty"
                       if index' a []          
                        then putStrLn "b is empty"
                        else                  
    where 
        index' :: [String] -> [String] -> [Int]
        index' a b = index' True [(elem x b) | x <- a]
```

If you indent your statement like this you'll see that the first if has no matching else clause.

Also, else clause doesn't return anything — a function should have a return value under all circumstances.